# An isosceles triangle with sides...

Tags: geometry

An isosceles triangle with sides $|AB|=6$, $|BC|=|AC|=5$. Calculate the height of the triangle, against the side $BC$.

I drew the following:

[image]

By the figure I get that $|CD|=\sqrt{25-x^2}$ and $|BD|=5-\sqrt{25-x^2}.$ Using the pythagorean theorem on $\triangle ABD,$ I get $$36=x^2+\left(5-\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)^2 \Longleftrightarrow x^2 = 25 - \frac{49}{25}.$$

Here is where the trouble starts. I'm not allowed to have a calculator to solve this, but I have to simplify the RHS and check if it is a perfect square. What I did with the RHS was this:

$$25-\frac{49}{25}=\frac{25^2-7^2}{25}=\frac{(25-7)(25+7)}{25}=\frac{18\cdot 32}{25}=\frac{3\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2^5}{5^2}=\frac{3^2(2^3)^2}{5^2}=\left(\frac{24}{5}\right)^2.$$

Thus the only positive solution is $x=\frac{24}{5},$ which indeed is correct. However time is of the essence here, doing that last simplification on the RHS took a while, on probably on a test, I'd just give up thinking I'm wrong because it's not supposed to be that much of arithmetic on these questions.

Is there any simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: I think that is probably the quickest way of doing it. One only needs to know that $24^2=576$ and $25^2=625$ (or that $(24, 7, 25)$ is a Pythagorean triple) to perform: $25-\frac{49}{25}=\frac{625-49}{25}=\frac{576}{25}=\frac{24^2}{5^2}$

Comment: Got you. Guess, there is no shortcut to this. Thanks mate!

Comment: Let $p=(5+5+6)/2=8$ be the semiperimeter. The by Heron formula $Area=\sqrt{8\cdot (8-5)(8-5)(8-6)}=\sqrt{16\cdot 9}=4\cdot 4=12$ thus $AD=\dfrac{2\cdot 12}{5}=\dfrac{24}{5}$. This is the shortest, if they don't let you  measure the height with a ruler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to solve this problem is to compute the area of the triangle using Heron's formula. In particular, $s = (6+5+5)/2=8$, and $A = \sqrt{8(8-6)(8-5)^2}=12$. But $A=\frac{5x}{2}$. Therefore, $x = \frac{24}{5}$.

Comment: Ah! Ofcourse, I actually know Heron's formula by heart. Should have thought of this! Ty!

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB,$  $AM = MB = 3$;

Consider the right $\triangle AMC.$

$AM= 3$;  $AC = 5;$

$ \Rightarrow$

$MC = 4,$ Pythagorean triple.

Area of $\triangle ABC = $

$ (1/2)AB×MC$= $(1/2)6×4 =$

$= (1/2) BC×AD = (1/2)5×h$,

where  $h:= AD$.

We get:  $h= 24/5$.